# why rds(aws) is showing db connection count 0?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds

> I am currently connected to rds via my website, but rds is saying db connections are 0

Can anybody tell me, is that right or that is something else.

Comment: how you checking the no of  connections and is your website actually making any DB connections when you checking that ?

Comment: A website rarely keeps a db connection open for a long time

Comment: @AmitK  actually there is around 400 users are active

Comment: I am also facing the same issue for the last few days. Though it's saving data after a certain time period but in the monitoring DB count is showing 0.

Comment: Did you get an answer on this?